# Markdown table to data frame in R

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, readr

There are numerous ways to convert a data frame into a Markdown table.
But how does one convert back to a dataframe, given a Markdown table

Given a table of a form:

```
Table Header | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Table Cell | Cell 2
Cell 3 | Cell 4
```

Or, even worse, in a form

```
Table Header | Second Header \n------------- | ------------- \nTable Cell | Cell 2 \nCell 3 | Cell 4
```

how does one get it into a data frame?

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a couple functions to deal with these issues, though I suspect this is more a problem for people writing SO answers than anyone else. Regardless:

```r
# base R version
read.markdown <- function(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, ...){
    if (length(file) > 1) {
        lines <- file
    } else if (grepl('\n', file)) {
        con <- textConnection(file)
        lines <- readLines(con)
        close(con)
    } else {
        lines <- readLines(file)
    }
    lines <- lines[!grepl('^[[:blank:]+-=:_|]*$', lines)]
    lines <- gsub('(^\\s*?\\|)|(\\|\\s*?$)', '', lines)
    read.delim(text = paste(lines, collapse = '\n'), sep = '|', 
               stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors, strip.white = strip.white, ...)
}

# readr version
read_markdown <- function(file, trim_ws = TRUE, ...){
    if (length(file) > 1) {
        lines <- file
    } else {
        lines <- readr::read_lines(file)
    }
    lines <- lines[!grepl('^[[:blank:]+-=:_|]*$', lines)]
    lines <- gsub('(^\\s*?\\|)|(\\|\\s*?$)', '', lines)
    readr::read_delim(paste(lines, collapse = '\n'), delim = '|', 
                      trim_ws = trim_ws, ...)
}
```

They can handle many variations of markdown tables, and are happy with a single string:

```r
read.markdown('Table Header | Second Header \n------------- | ------------- \nTable Cell | Cell 2 \nCell 3 | Cell 4 ')
#>   Table.Header Second.Header
#> 1   Table Cell        Cell 2
#> 2       Cell 3        Cell 4
```

a vector of lines (like one gets from `clipr::read_clip`):

```r
clipr::write_clip(
' |                     |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |
 |:-------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|
 |      Mazda RX4      |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
 |    Mazda RX4 Wag    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
 |     Datsun 710      | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |'
)

read.markdown(clipr::read_clip())
#>               X  mpg cyl disp  hp
#> 1     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110
#> 3    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93
```

or a filename (though the file can only contain the table and whitespace):

```r
tmp <- tempfile()
writeLines(
' +---------------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
 |                     |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |  drat  |
 +=====================+=======+=======+========+======+========+
 |      Mazda RX4      |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   |
 +---------------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
 |    Mazda RX4 Wag    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   |
 +---------------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+
 |     Datsun 710      | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |  3.85  |
 +---------------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+',
tmp
)

read_markdown(tmp)
#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   X1              mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Mazda RX4      21.0     6   160   110  3.90
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6   160   110  3.90
#> 3 Datsun 710     22.8     4   108    93  3.85
```

---

**Edit:** I've put these functions in [a package](https://alistaire47.github.io/read.so/), should anyone find them useful.

Comment: Can this be done with a markdown table that has inline code? So a cell like `r 21` becomes 21 in the data frame rather than the character `r 21`.

Comment: Like `... | \`r 21\` | ...`? Sure, but it's more work. Iterating `glue::glue` across any character columns (with `.open = '\`r', close = '\`'` would work.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you for providing the `read.so` package – It works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

I typed up the question, but then realized that answer is quite simple.
Function `read_delim` in `readr` package handles this easily:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

object <- 'Table Header | Second Header \n------------- | ------------- \nTable Cell | Cell 2 \nCell 3 | Cell 4'
data_frame <- read_delim(object, delim = '|')

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `Table Header ` ` Second Header `
            <chr>             <chr>
1  -------------     ------------- 
2     Table Cell            Cell 2 
3         Cell 3             Cell 4
```

One would only need to filter out the '-------' row. Et voila.

Hope this solution helps someone.