# R: is it possible to convert a knitr::kable to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, knitr, kable

I am using the `pivot` function from the lessR package, to create an Excel-like pivot table with two categorical variables that make up the vertical and horizontal categories, and a mean in each cell. (Hope this makes sense).

I followed the code that the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lessR/vignettes/pivot.html) gives. Let's follow their example:

```
d <- Read("Employee")
a <- pivot(d, mean, Salary, Dept, Gender)
```

The data `d` is like this:

```
                    Years Gender Dept    Salary JobSat Plan Pre Post
Ritchie, Darnell        7      M ADMN  53788.26    med    1  82   92
Wu, James              NA      M SALE  94494.58    low    1  62   74
Hoang, Binh            15      M SALE 111074.86    low    3  96   97
Jones, Alissa           5      F <NA>  53772.58   <NA>    1  65   62
Downs, Deborah          7      F FINC  57139.90   high    2  90   86
Afshari, Anbar          6      F ADMN  69441.93   high    2 100  100
Knox, Michael          18      M MKTG  99062.66    med    3  81   84
Campagna, Justin        8      M SALE  72321.36    low    1  76   84
Kimball, Claire         8      F MKTG  61356.69   high    2  93   92
```

The pivottable `a` is a nice table, exactly as I want it to look in terms of cell contents, etc. It appears to be a knitr_kable.

```
 Gender  F          M               
 Dept                        
-------  ---------  ---------
   ACCT   63237.16   59626.20
   ADMN   81434.00   80963.35
   FINC   57139.90   72967.60
   MKTG   64496.02   99062.66
   SALE   64188.25   86150.97
```

Next, I would like to make a dataframe out of this, for easier manipulation in my code and for copying it to the clipboard. However, I don't know how to convert a knitr_kable to a dataframe. Here is my code and the error it results in:

```
as.data.frame(a)

Error in as.data.frame.default(a) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"knitr_kable"’ to a data.frame
```

The knitr-documentation does not say anything about this conversion - it is only about converting a dataframe to a `knitr_kable`, which is the opposite of what I want.

I have also tried `pivottabler`, but this has similar issues: the resulting class cannot be coerced to a dataframe either.

Comment: Why not just work with the data that the kable was made from?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest `library(tidyverse); d %>% group_by(Dept, Gender) %>% summarize(value = mean(Salary), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = value)`

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is what I will end up using, or maybe the tidyr option that was suggested below. Both deliver what I need! The difference is that you added .groups="drop", what does that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two potential answers:

### Most direct: Wrangle the data yourself

If you're open to a **tidyverse**-style approach, it only takes a few lines to do the wrangling and summarising yourself. That will give you a datatable output that you can work with right away.

```
# load packages
library(lessR)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# load data
d <- Read("Employee")

# use tidyverse-style code to pivot and summarise the data yourself
d %>%
  group_by(Gender, Dept) %>%
  summarise(Salary_mean = mean(Salary)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from= "Gender", values_from = "Salary_mean")
```

### Read the knitr::kable() markdown output into a data frame

If you prefer to work backwards from a `knitr::kable()` output to a dataframe, this is addressed in this SO question: [Markdown table to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087762/markdown-table-to-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: I liked the tidyverse option, this worked well. Thanks!  The markdown-reverse looked a bit 'overdone' for my problem.

Comment: Thanks! If it was helpful, please don't forget to accept my answer :)